# highlighting custom function keyword after (.) period

Tags: ace-editor

I have custom function keyword like ToString, ToUpper, ToLower etc. I want to highlight these function keyword after (.) dot

i have changed the "support.function" in the highlight rules.
But it is highlighting without (.), if i put (.) before the function name, then it is not highlighting.

i have modified like this, except this everything is same.

```
    var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
            "variable.language": "M|D|H|S|Now|ATime|ETime",
            "keyword": "Double|DateTime|String|if|then|else|endif|CTYPE",
            "storage.type":"",
            "constant.language":"",
            "support.function": "Abs|Ceil|Exp|Floor|Log|ln|Pow|Round|Sqrt|cos|sin|tan|cosh|sinh|tanh|acos|asin|atan|Max" +
                                "|Min|Sum|Std|Var|Average|Norm|Median|Count|TWA|Interpolate|Bitset|Bitget|Range|Group" +
                                "|ROC|Ema|IsNan|IsNull|IsBad|ReplaceBadValue|OverrideValue|LogMsg|ThrowError|Quality|Filter" +
                                "|DTValue|Time|DTAdd|Age|SubString|Replace|Trim|Length|ToLower|.ToUpper|ToNumber|ToString|Contains",
            "constant.language.boolean": "true|false"
        }, "identifier");

        var kwBeforeRe = "if|then";
```

Comment: are you adding this to an existing mode or to a new mode, it would be helpful if you could add code example showing what you have tried.

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the regexp of the state to which keywordMapper is applied, it doesn't match dot, you most likely need to add a new state for the properties after dot similar to [javascript mode](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.4.5/lib/ace/mode/javascript_highlight_rules.js#L202) and add another keyowrdMapper for that state.